# zsh is not splitting by IFS after parameter expansion

Tags: bash, shell, posix, zsh, ifs

This is my code to loop over colon separated values and do something
with each value.

```
f()
{
    IFS=:
    for arg in $1
    do
        echo arg: $arg
    done
}

f foo:bar:baz
```

This works fine in most POSIX compliant shells.

```
$ dash foo.sh
arg: foo
arg: bar
arg: baz
$ bash foo.sh
arg: foo
arg: bar
arg: baz
$ ksh foo.sh
arg: foo
arg: bar
arg: baz
$ posh foo.sh
arg: foo
arg: bar
arg: baz
$ yash foo.sh
arg: foo
arg: bar
arg: baz
```

But it does not work as expected in zsh.

```
$ zsh foo.sh
arg: foo:bar:baz
```

Is zsh in violation of [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05) here?

Comment: Yes, zsh is knowingly and intentionally in violation here. That said, relying on string-splitting isn't a good practice in *any* shell -- even in bash, I'd encourage you to use `read -r -a args <<<"$1"` or such to read into an array, then `for arg in "${args[@]}"; do ...`

Comment: This is a case where `zsh` does what POSIX *should* do, it POSIX hadn't been burdened with maintaining existing behavior as much as possible. As the worst possible solution, you could use `setopt SH_WORD_SPLIT` to restore the POSIX behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Zsh has chosen its own way.

Here is the zsh faq entry:
[“3.1: Why does $var where var="foo bar" not do what I expect?”](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq03.html#31)

In this particular case, you could workaround by adding the [`-y`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-SH_005fWORD_005fSPLIT) option to the `zsh` invocation:

```
$ zsh -y foo.sh
arg: foo
arg: bar
arg: baz
```

---

You could take a look at [the zsh's faq](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq.html) especially the chapter 2 and 3.
The more you've experienced other shells, the more you can find zsh's pitfalls.

Answer (score 2):

In Zsh it is usually cleaner to split with the provided `(s)` flag (vs using `IFS`).
A solution for your data would then be:

```
% f() { for e in ${(s.:.)1}; print $e }
% f foo:bar:baz
foo
bar
baz
```

See the *PARAMETER EXPANSION* section in `zshexpn(1)` man page for
more details and related flags.

(I assume you mean *colon*-separated values.)

Comment: I felt quite ok writing shell command scripts using Ruby... and then I tried to learn more Bash and Zsh,,, but they seem like Martian language to me