# IFS working as expected when in bash, not working properly in zsh

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, ifs

OS: Monetary (12.0.1)
default shell: zsh (5.8)

```
#!/bin/zsh

LINE="I:would:like:coffee."
IFS=:
set $LINE

echo $1
echo $2
echo $3
echo $4

exit 0
```

```
./script.sh
```

```
zsh ./script.sh
```

Both ways of running the script returned

```
I:would:like:coffee.
```

Only when running in bash, did the script work as expected

```
bash ./script.sh
```

```
I
would
like
coffee.
```

I do want to know that the reason why IFS works as expected in bash, not in zsh.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [zsh is not splitting by IFS after parameter expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46313940/7939871)

Comment: Short answer: zsh does not not provide POSIX-shell compatibility in its default operation mode.
Or duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/46313940/7939871

Comment: @LéaGris The link exactly answered what I was wondering, thanks.

Comment: In the zsh-version of your script, do a `set ${(z)LINE}` instead. However,what's the point in using `set`? Wouldn't it make more sense to create an explicit array of the words in `LINE`, and work with the array?

Comment: For zsh, there is no need to change IFS. You can do a `linearr=(${(@s,:,)LINE})`. After this, i.e. `echo $linearr[2]` prints _would_, since this is the second part of your string. Search [here](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) for the term _field splitting_ to understand why this works.

Comment: `IFS` works exactly as expected in both shells. The difference is that in `zsh`, an unquoted parameter expansion is *not* (by default) subject to word-splitting, which is what `IFS` affects.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like ZSH feature. See on [ZSH FAQs](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/FAQ/zshfaq03.html#31).
For only one script you can use -y flag.

```
zsh -y ./script.sh
```

Comment: Don't forget to also check possible duplicates like: [zsh is not splitting by IFS after parameter expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46313940/7939871)